# Visual Studio from CMake - Debug/Release not found

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, cmake, gitlab-ci-runner

A gitlab-runner configuration script `.gitlab-ci.yml`, for execution in the Powershell:

```
windows:
  tags:
  - windows
  stage: build
  script:
    - New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Confirm:$false -Force:$true -Name "build"
    - cd build
    - cmd.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
    - cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 -T host=x64 -B. ..
    - cmake -j8 --build . --config Debug
    - ctest -j4
```

results in

```
$ cmd.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
[...]
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/gitlab-runner/builds/xxxxxxxx/build
$ cmake -j8 --build . --config Debug
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/gitlab-runner/builds/xxxxxxxx/build/Debug" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

How to resolve this conflict between the configure step (`cmake`) and
the build step (`cmake --build`)?

The latter won't work without the option `--config Debug`;
but if that option is given, then it looks for a nonexistent directory.

Same problem with `--config Release`.

Disclosure: cross-posting from the CMake mailing list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordering of command line arguments to `cmake` matters in this case. For build mode, the `--build` option must be the first one listed, but the `-j8` option has been put before it. Change the build command to the following and it should work:

```
cmake --build . --config Debug -j8
```

The ordering requirement is documented for the `--build` option in the [Build A Project](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project) section of the cmake manual.